# I am trying to initialise a Base Class property in a Sub Class but I am getting an error

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to make this Sub Class Circle inherit the traits of parent class Shapes. I want the Circle Class to accept a colour string but I keep getting an error.

```
class Circle extends Shapes {
    private int radius;
    public Circle(int radius, String Colour) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.colour = Colour;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> 'colour' has private access in 'Shapes'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code would be *much* easier to read if it were formatted appropriately. Please get your IDE to format the code, then read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make sure it appears that way in your post. Beyond that: yes, `colour` is private, so you can't set it within `Circle`. You could call `setColour` though

Comment: Yes, you'd call `setColour` *passing in the colour you want to set*. (That's the point of the method.) You don't use a method call as the left hand side of an assignment, because it's not a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The error I get is 'colour' has private acces in 'Shapes'

Because `colour` is indeed `private`:

```
private String colour = "Red";
```

And `Circle` is trying to access that field directly:

```
this.colour = Colour;
```

If you want to set it from outside of `Shapes` (such as in `Circle`) then you can use your setter method.  For example:

```
public Circle(int radius, String Colour) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.setColour(Colour);
}
```

Another alternative could be to make the field `protected` instead of `private` so inheriting classes can directly access it.  But unless there's a compelling reason to do so, it's generally best to keep fields `private` and allow the use of getters/setters to access them.  Since in this case there's a `public` setter, it's simple enough to just use that.

(As an aside, consider changing your variable's name from `Colour` to `colour` to better conform to Java naming standards.)